# Iterate nested array which is dynamically created

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, each object MAY contain more arrays of objects and so on. I want to iterate through all these objects without hard coding it. I don't know how many nested arrays will each object have.

```
// This is the parent array
var members = [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object];

// members[0] can have another array of objects
var member = members[0];

and so on....
var mem = member[0];
```

I want to iterate through all those objects, but like I said, I can't know how many there will be. I need to get label of every object which I currently get by Object.label
I hope I explained it well, here's the picture.
Array[5] is var members in my example
[image]

Comment: So you loop over the array and read the label? And when you encounter the next object, you do recursion and loop over that.

Comment: You can use recursion. But this will need a standard object structure

Answer (score 3):

I would solve this with a recursive function that iterates through all children. Given they all share the same structure.

```
function visit(o) {
  for (var i = 0; i<o.length; i++) {        
    /* do something useful */
    console.log(o[i].label);

    if (Array.isArray(o[i].children)) {
      visit(o[i].children);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it working. your o in if should be with [ i ]. So    

    if (o[i].children) {
      visit(o[i].children);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```js
function getMembers(list){
  list.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.label); 
    if(item.children){
      getMembers(item.children)
    }
  });
}

var members = [{label: 'label1', children:[{label: 'label21'}, {label: 'label22'}]}, {label: 'label2'}, {label: 'label3'}];

getMembers(members);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Check whether child element is array using Js **[Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)** and if it is array call the function **someFn** again

```
function someFn(members) {
var labels=[]
for (var i = 0; i<members.length; i++) { 
    labels.push(members[i].label)

    if (Array.isArray(members[i]) && members[i].length>0) {
      someFn(members[i]);
    }
  }
retun labels;
}
var membersArray = [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object];
var labelsArray= someFn(membersArray);
console.log(labelsArray);
```

I'll add some demo later

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that given an `object` it will read `label` property in this object and loop throught `children` array of this object if it exists.

```
function readObj(obj){
  console.log(obj.label);
  if(obj.children && obj.children.length>0){
       obj.children.map(readObj);
  }
}
```

And then apply this function to all `members` array.

```js
function readObj(obj) {
  console.log(obj.label);
  if (obj.children && obj.children.length > 0) {
    obj.children.map(readObj);
  }
}

var members = [{
  label: "label1"
}, {
  label: "Label2",
  children: [{
    label: "child1"
  }, {
    label: "child2"
  }]
}, {
  label: "label3",
  children: [{
    label: "child3"
  }]
}];

members.map(readObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var jsonArr = [{"children":["New1","New2","New3","New4"]},{"children1":
                  ["New11","New12","New13","New14"],"children2":
                  ["New21","New22","New23","New24"]},{"children2":
                  ["New21","New22","New23","New24"]}];

 function callRecFunc(obj){
  $.each(obj,function(i,o){
   if(o != undefined && o instanceof Array){
    callRecFunc(o);
   }
   else{
    console.log(o);
   }
  });
 }

 $.each(jsonArr,function(ind,obj){
   callRecFunc(obj);
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try out this code, this recursion is work for all the nested arrays and after that it will print array element data. But at the leaf node there must be a simple array with values